# Matrix of adjoint operator in Hermitian inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(e_1,e_2)$ be an orthonormal basis of Hermitian inner product space, an operator $f$ in the basis $(e_1+ie_2,ie_1-2e_2)$ has the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
i & -2 \\
2i & -3
\end{pmatrix}$. Find the matrix of adjoint operator $f^*$ in this basis.

**My approach:** Let's denote the new basis by $e'_1,e'_2$ i.e. $e'_1=e_1+ie_2, e'_2=ie_1-2e_2$. Also one can show that $$A_{f^*}^{(e')}=G^{-1}[A_{f}^{(e')}]^*G$$ where by $A_g^{(e')}$ I denote the matrix of an operator $g$ in the basis $\{e'_1,e'_2\}$, $G$ denotes the Gram matrix of vectors $\{e'_1,e'_2\}$ and $B^*:=\overline{B^T}$.

One can compute that: $(e'_1,e'_1)=(e_1+ie_2,e_1+ie_2)=1-i^2=2$, $(e'_1,e'_2)=(e_1+ie_2,ie_1-2e_2)=3i, (e'_2,e'_2)=(ie_1-2e_2,ie_1-2e_2)=-i^2+4=5.$

It shows that $G=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3i \\
3i & 5
\end{pmatrix}$ and $G^{-1}=\frac{1}{19}\begin{pmatrix}
5 & -3i \\
-3i & 2
\end{pmatrix}$ and  $[A_{f}^{(e')}]^*=\begin{pmatrix}
-i & -2i \\
-2 & -3
\end{pmatrix}$. Then $$A_{f^*}^{(e')}=\frac{1}{19}\begin{pmatrix}
5 & -3i \\
-3i & 2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-i & -2i \\
-2 & -3
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3i \\
3i & 5
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{19}\begin{pmatrix}
2i+3 & -3-5i \\
-14-36i & -21i-60
\end{pmatrix}$$

However the answer in the book is equal to $\begin{pmatrix}
-3+2i & -3-5i \\
-2 & -3i
\end{pmatrix}$.

I have checked my computation and my reasoning about 4 times but I cannot find my mistake. Maybe the book's answer is wrong.

Would grateful for any help and comments!

Comment: Note that $G$ should be Hermitian. In particular, $G_{12} = -3i$.

Comment: $(e_2',e_1') = \overline{ (e_1',e_2')}$.

Comment: @copper.hat, ohh man! I am so stupid! OMG :) I feel my self the most stupid right now) I did not notice this tiny detail. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Please sorry for this stupid question :)

Comment: No problem, glad to be able to help :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a matter of grinding carefully through the computations.

Let $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ i & -2 \end{bmatrix}$ and
$N=\begin{bmatrix} i & -2 \\ 2i & -3  \end{bmatrix}$.
($B$ maps new coordinates into old coordinates.)

Then the matrix of $f$ in the old basis is $O = B N B^{-1}$ and the matrix of $f^*$ in the new basis is
$B^{-1} O^* B = B^{-1} B^{-*}N^* B B^*$ which computes to the answer in the book.

Comment: I am quite confused with your notation. But what is wrong with my computation?

Comment: I do not see why $G_{12}$ should be $-3i$. It is $3i$.

Comment: Moreover, in your solution you do not use Gram matrix which you have to

Comment: Did you read my comment to the question!!!

Comment: Yes but i did not get it. I just want to know what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: The above is just doing a change of basis, $B$ is the map from new coordinates into old coordinates.

Comment: Your $G$ is incorrect. $G$ must be Hermitian. That is what I wrote in the comment.

Comment: Your $G$ is equivalent to my $B B^*$ above.